# Can I safely delete all content in /var/lib/php5?

Tags: php, session

I have over 5 million session files in `/var/lib/php5`
I would like to delete all files in this folder using `rm *`, however I'm not sure if there are other files other than the session files in that directory that should not be deleted.

Through SSH it took a few minutes to make the file count and I'm not sure I can navigate through there with all these random filenames.
The setup is ubuntu lucid linx, apache 2 and php5. In the most common of setups are there other folders / files in `/var/lib/php5` that I should not delete?

**Edit** The reason I want to remove the files is because I moved session handling to a database and don't need any of the files anymore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let PHP's gc perform cleanup by itself. Find php.ini and change `session.gc_probability` to something bigger, save it and restart Apache (call any php script). It says here http://somethingemporium.com/2007/06/obscure-error-with-php5-on-debian-ubuntu-session-phpini-garbage

> In Debian and Ubuntu, /var/lib/php5, where the session data is stored,
>   has permissions of drwx-wx-wt and should only be cleaned by a cron
>   script. So, the package maintainers disable automatic session garbage
>   collection.

Or you could try to put `ini_set('session.gc_probability', 100); session_start();` (if your `session.gc_divisor` is equal to 100) in one of your scripts and call it. The best way is to put in empty php file, because it might perform cleanup for a very long period of time.

ps: I would also try to leave `session.gc_probability` 1 and set `session.gc_divisor` to 1. It should call gc at every run, but you need it just for a directory cleanup.

And check your cron `/etc/cron.d/php5` - it should run every half an hour to purge session files in the /var/lib/php5/ directory.

pps: found interesting comment

> This does not disable it (it is commented out). The default within the
>   engine is still used - phpinfo() shows the value to be 1. There is a
>   problem with garbage collection in Debian (and thus Ubuntu) but that's
>   due to PHP wanting to vacuum garbage that has already been removed by
>   the cron script. This causes an error that may be displayed on the
>   unlucky page.

Comment: Changing these settings will delete all old session files? In fact I just want to get rid of all files asap, the session lifetime however is set to 2 weeks.

Comment: @Moak yes, it will delete obsolete data. You could change also the timelife just for cleanup run. BTW, do you have any specific part in the name of the session file? you could filter by it if you want. Anyway, check cron job and run it.

Comment: In my case (SuSE 11.2) it didn’t work at first. I found out that changes to `php.ini` get applied when I issued `rcapache2 reload`.

Answer (score 26):

```
cd /var/lib/php5
find . -name "sess_*" -print | xargs rm -v
```

Comment: Why not just `rm -v /var/lib/php5/sess_*`?

Comment: Because with an obscenely large amount of files, `rm` will quit prematurely with an "Argument list too long" error, and not actually delete any files. Finding the files using `find` and piping the results one by one to `xargs` steps around this limitataion. [More information](http://www.moundalexis.com/archives/000035.php)

Answer (score 1):

in `PHP7`, this worked

```
cd /var/lib/php/sessions/
sudo find . -name "sess_*" -print |sudo xargs rm -v
```

If you're using `CODEIGNITER`, then try with following commands.

```
cd /var/lib/php/sessions/
sudo find . -name "ci_*" -print |sudo xargs rm -v
sudo find . -name "cises*" -print |sudo xargs rm -v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /var/lib/php5
sudo find . -name "sess_*" -print |sudo xargs rm -v
```

This has worked in my case .

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu computer, at /var/lib/php5, there is a sess ID file:
sess_a7kjdaojmneuhcgslj

If I tried to remove this file using the command:

sudo rm sess_a7*

I got an error message saying there is no such a file. I had to use the full name as:

sudo rm sess_a7kjdaojmneuhcgslj

It worked. This is my two cents.